# Using multiple criteria with a dataframe filter() function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to do something like this -

```
df.groupby('brand').filter(lambda group: (len(group) >= 10) | (group.brand == "ABC") )
```

Filtering the dataframe down to records that either have 10 or more occurrences when grouped by `brand`, OR if the records `brand` attribute matches one specific value I want to keep those as well.

Seems that I'm still a ways off and maybe `filter` can't take multiple criteria.

Comment: Do you need `df[(df.groupby('brand').transform('size') >= 10) | (df['brand'] == 'ABC')]`?

Comment: When I try that it gives an error on the transform criteria - `Transform function invalid for data types`

Answer (score 0):

Use `(group.brand == "ABC").all()` as the condition when you want *all* values in `group['brand']` to equal `"ABC"`. Otherwise, in a boolean context, `bool(group.brand == "ABC")` raises

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2019)
N = 10
df = pd.DataFrame({'brand':np.random.choice(['ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'], size=N),
                   'val':np.random.randint(4, size=N)})
result = df.groupby('brand').filter(lambda group: (len(group) >= 3)
                                    | (group['brand'] == "ABC").all())
print(result)
```

yields

```
  brand  val
0   ABC    0
1   GHI    0
3   ABC    0
4   GHI    1
5   GHI    3
6   ABC    0
8   ABC    2
9   GHI    3
```